# SyntaxError on MySql Db Insert

Tags: mysql, web2py

I'm currently working on a project that allows users to perform self-evaluations.  Currently, I store the criteria for the evaluation in a MySQL table and iterate through that table to make the FORM object, appending a drop down list to each row.  Although this creates the form with ease, when I put the insert command inside the form acceptance conditional block, I get a syntax error on the first field assignment that uses an underscore.  Here is the code for the table:

```
db.define_table('Evaluation', Field('EvaluationId', 'integer', 'id'), 
Field('PersonBeingEvaluated', db.Person, 'integer'), 
Field('PersonEvaluating', 'integer'), 
Field('EvalDate', 'datetime'), 
Field('1_1A', 'integer'), Field('1_1B', 'integer'), Field('1_2', 'integer'),
Field('1_3', 'integer'), Field('1_4', 'integer'), Field('1_5', 'integer'), 
Field('1_6', 'integer'), Field('2_1', 'integer'), Field('2_2A', 'integer'),
Field('2_2B', 'integer'), Field('2_3A', 'integer'), Field('2_3B', 'integer'), 
Field('2_4', 'integer'), Field('2_5', 'integer'), Field('3_1', 'integer'), 
Field('3_2', 'integer'), Field('3_3', 'integer'), Field('3_4', 'integer'), 
Field('3_5A', 'integer'), Field('3_5B', 'integer'), Field('3_6', 'integer'), 
Field('3_7', 'integer'), Field('3_8', 'integer'), Field('3_9A', 'integer'), 
Field('3_9B', 'integer'), Field('3_9C', 'integer'), Field('4_1', 'integer'), 
Field('4_2', 'integer'), Field('4_3A', 'integer'), Field('4_3B', 'integer'), 
Field('4_4', 'integer'), Field('BeliefsScore', 'integer'), 
Field('CharacterScore', 'integer'), primarykey=['EvaluationId'])
```

And the code for my method:

```
@auth.requires_login()
def Take_Eval(): 
    user = db(db.Person.auth_userUserId == auth.user.id).select().first().PersonId
    table = db(db.PageContent.ContentId > 0).select()

    accordion = DIV(_id="accordion")
    for row in table:
        accordion.append(H2(row['ContentDescription'], _style="padding-left: 10px;"))
        accordion.append(DIV(XML(row.ContentHTML), BR(), P(SELECT(OPTGROUP(OPTION('Does not Attempt', _value=0), 
        OPTION('Developing', _value=1), OPTION('Progressing', _value=2), OPTION('Established', _value=3), 
        OPTION('Advanced', _value=4), OPTION('Master', _value=5)), _id=row['QuestionNumber']), _style='text-align: center;')))


    form = FORM(accordion, BR(), P(INPUT(_type='submit', _value='Submit', _name='btnSubmit'), _style="text-align: center;"))

    if form.accepts(request, session):
        response.flash = 'Evaluation Saved Successfully on  ' + str(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))
        db.Evaluation.insert(PersonBeingEvaluated=user, PersonEvaluating=0, EvalDate=datetime.now(), 
        1_1A = form.vars.1_1A, 1_1B = form.vars.1_1B, 1_2 = form.vars.1_2, 1_3 = form.vars.1_3, 
        1_4 = form.vars.1_4, 1_5 = form.vars.1_5, 1_6 = form.vars.1_6, 2_1 = form.vars.2_1, 
        2_2A = form.vars.2_2A, 2_2B = form.vars.2_2B, 2_3A = form.vars.2_3A, 2_3B = form.vars.2_3B, 
        2_4 = form.vars.2_4, 2_5 = form.vars.2_5, 3_1 = form.vars.3_1, 3_2 = form.vars.3_2, 
        3_3 = form.vars.3_3, 3_4 = form.vars.3_4, 3_5A = form.vars.3_5A, 3_5B = form.vars.3_5B, 
        3_6 = form.vars.3_6, 3_7 = form.vars.3_7, 3_8 = form.vars.3_8, 3_9A = form.vars.3_9A, 
        3_9B = form.vars.3_9B, 3_9C = form.vars.3_9C, 4_1 = form.vars.4_1, 4_2 = form.vars.4_2, 
        4_3A = form.vars.4_3A, 4_3B = form.vars.4_3B, 4_4 = form.vars.4_4, 
        BeliefsScore = form.vars.BeliefsScore, CharacterScore = form.vars.CharacterScore)

        redirect(URL('default', 'index'))
    elif form.errors:
            response.flash = 'Profile could not be submitted.  Please try again later. '   

    return locals()
```

In order to resolve this issue, I've refactored the form, believing that perhaps my naming convention was wrong for the drop down lists.  However, I don't believe that is the case.  I've also tried using something along the lines of:

```
1_1A = form.vars.1_1A.value
```

Thinking that maybe I was assigning the drop down list instead of its numerical value, but that didn't change the error code either.  The optimal solution to this problem would be to get the code to compile correctly and have each drop down list submit an integer to the database on insert.

Can anyone tell me why the syntax for my insert method errors out?  Thanks.

**EDIT** :

Here's the HTML page:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion({ 
            header: "h2",
            autoHeight: false
         });

    });  
</script>


<h1>Evaluation Info</h1>
<br />
<div id="contentPane">
    {{=form}}
</div>


<br />
```

The actual page itself is several thousand lines long; however, I also grabbed a markup for on of the select tags:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><select id="Q1_1A"><optgroup>
    <option value="0">Does not Attempt</option>
    <option value="1">Developing</option>
    <option value="2">Progressing</option>
    <option value="3">Established</option>
    <option value="4">Advanced</option>
    <option value="5">Master</option>
</optgroup></select></p>
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: never use numbers as beginning of a variable name

Comment: That corrected part of the problem, thanks.  I've prefixed all of the variables with 'Q'.  All of the drop down lists currently return null when I try to insert the record to the database.  Any idea why?

Comment: include the html part please